# distributing my java app, HOW do I manage directories

Tags: java, swing, deployment, distribution

My java applications is almost complete and now I am giving it a finishing touch. Although certain code requires to read data from specific directories on the computer. On my machine I did it in the following way:

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(C:/User/AnirudhVarma/Document/Appname/foldername/file,true);
```

But on the users machine how do I ensure that it creates it in the following directory?

```
C:/enduser/appname/folder/file
```

Comment: 1) *"read data from specific directories"*  What data specifically?  2) A better deployment strategy is probably to launch the app. from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 2):

Hard coding folder structure in code is very bad idea.

One way to handle this is:

You need to have a properties file something like that where user need to enter path to required folder. Mention this as requirement in install docs.

In your code you need to make sure folder has required content before proceeding. If not valid folder, just show error message with proper information to setup the directory path.

Answer (score 1):

`System.getProperty("user.dir")` will return `C:/User/AnirudhVarma` on you machine.  From there, I'd suggest you need to consider the platform.  Under windows, you should store this kind of information into the `AppData` folder.

So you would end up with something like `System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.seperator + "AppData/Appname/foldername/file"`

Under MacOS, I believe the convention is to use `.AppName` instead, something like `System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.seperator + ".Appname/foldername/file"`